# Chromium snap bookmarks lost

Tags: 20.04, snap, chromium, bookmarks

I had a bunch of issues with Chromium on Ubuntu 20.04, which was installed using Software Center (particularly in relation to fonts). So I removed Chromium from Software Center and now I can't find any of my bookmarks.

Comment: *I removed Chromium from Software Center* -- Where are you trying to find bookmarks now that Chromium is not there? Also note that Google has removed the sync feature in Chromium.

Comment: Searched in ~/snap/Chromium

Comment: Historically deleting Chrome didn't nuke your bookmarks. They used to be saved in a .config folder

Comment: They are still saved in a config folder, under the snap folder. Cannot tell exactly where: I do not have snap.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into a similar problem where I was previously using a non-snap Chromium, then I upgraded Ubuntu and that forced a switch to snap Chromium, which apparently uses a slightly different path to store settings. The effect was that I had a brand new profile, missing all my previous settings and data.

The solution I found, based on [this answer](https://superuser.com/questions/1383425/where-does-chromium-store-bookmarks-and-browsing-history-in-ubuntu) was close Chromium, then copy the `Bookmarks` file at `~/.config/chromium/Profile 1` to the new default snap settings directory at `~/snap/chromium/common/chromium/Default`.

After relaunching Chromium, all my bookmarks were back.

Assuming either of those paths, or something similar, still exist on your filesystem, your bookmarks still exist. However, if the uninstall purged those, then they might be lost forever. Try doing a search in your `~/.config` and `~/snap` directories for any files named "Bookmarks".